# Browserify & Jstify: "Unexpected token %="

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, node-modules

So ... I'm fairly new with Browserify and giving a shot at rebuilding an AMD project with it.  However, in any scenario where I would have been using `tpl!` to require my templates with RequireJS, I'll have, ex:

`var QuoteTemplate= require('js/quoting/quote/quoteTemplate');`

but when I run the CLI, using this example taken from https://github.com/zertosh/jstify

`browserify -t [ jstify --minifierOpts [ --collapseWhitespace false ] ] js/quoting/app.js > js-dist/quoting.js`

at the first instance of a JS tag in the template I get

`ParseError: Unexpected token %=`

...which frankly is the *exact* token I was expecting it to *expect*.

I'm picking on jstify here but I've also tried it with node-underscorify and with Handlebars as well (modifying my template, of course, it still chokes on the `.` in my dot syntax but I don't play much with hbs, so, idk) ... my point being that perhaps I have misunderstood something silly and could be straightened out easily...?  Maybe?

Comment: I'm using Browserify 6.1.0 and Jstify 0.7.0, fwiw

Comment: what is the file extension of `quoteTemplate` in the `jstify` case. looking at the `jstify` code it should be `"jst"`, `"tpl"`, `"html"`, or `"ejs"`. if its not one of those, the transform will not be applied and will get browserified as javascript and cause the parse error. could that be whats happening for you?

Comment: The filename is `quoteTemplate.tpl`.  Sorry for not thinking to include that.

I'm not positive if I'm supposed to use the extension in the require call or not.  That's what I do with RequireJS and `tpl!` but I get the impression that I shouldn't do it here.  I've tried it both ways to varying degrees of failure.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  Well, I'm not sure if this is exactly an *answer* in the classic sense, but now that I've gotten another shot at this I've decided just to recreate it using an extra step:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var QuoterTemplate = _.template(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/quote/quoteTemplate.tpl', 'utf8'));
```

And then I'm using the `[brfs]`[1](https://github.com/substack/brfs) transform to pull that template in, to be turned into a template function by Underscore.

So... I may go to my grave not understanding why I was having this problem, but at least I'll be able to load templates this way before I die.  Hope this helps somebody!